# Led ceiling light has extra wires!

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, light-fixture, ceiling

I recently bought a ceiling light from Costco. The Artika - Zane.

The fixture has 
2x black (one is thin)
2x white (one is thin)
1x gray (thin)
1x red
1x copper(grounding)

My ceiling only has
1x black
1x white
1x copper

I tried:
- Connecting the whites and gray together as well as the blacks with the red.
- I have also tried without the red and gray connected.

I'm no electrician and don't have any friends with any electrical background.

Please help!

Comment: What do the instructions say to do?

Comment: Is that red really red, or could it be leaning towards purple? If it were purple then gray/purple is the standard for a low-voltage (0-10V) dimming input (and connecting them to hot/neutral may have killed the device.

Comment: The instructions do not mention or even show the other wire but the 1 black, 1 white and copper.

Comment: The red wire is definitely red.

Comment: Pictures of the fixture would be very helpful

Answer (score 2):

I'm having trouble finding an exact match on the Artika site, and the Costco site (as usual) does not list all the products found in stores. The products that I checked manuals on the Artika site have no mention of the other wires.

My hunch is that the thick black, thick white and copper ground wires should be attached to the matching ceiling wires, and that the other wires are for daisy-chaining to additional matching fixtures. Unfortunately, without a manual it is hard to tell for sure. I would try connecting just those 3 wires and cap (wire-nut) the thin wires for safety (each one separately) and see if that works.